# cygwin permissions are too open

Tags: ssh, permissions

Yesterday, I was able to ssh to my amazon server on my windows cygwin terminal, but today I'm greeted with an error. I think I might've mistyped an option in the ssh command and it's locking me out or messed up the fingerprint (yes/no) option.

thanks in advance

I've tried the solutions: chmod 400 filename and chmod 600 filename
and I still get the same error.

heres a screenshot: [image]

I've tried chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using a copy of the same .pem file when the original .pem file worked already. I just deleted the copy and copied the original .pem file to the directory and it worked.